# How to perform the following join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Assuming I have the following tables:

tableA

```
id|first_name|sport
1 | alice | swimming
2 | bob | basketball
3 | casey | baseball
```

tableB

```
name | hobby
alice | running
bob | null
```

I want to get an output table similar to tableA but with an additional column of:

```
id | first_name | sport | theirhobby
1 | alice | swimming | running
2 | bob | basketball | null
3 | casey | baseball | null
```

Note that the name of the column for names is retained from tableA and the only new column appended to tableA is the hobby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.first_name, a.sport,
        b.hobby
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN tableB b
            ON a.first_name = b.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f747/2)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Is there a way to append the one column from tableB without explicitly naming every column from tableA?

Comment: @SeiSeiei use `SELECT *`, the disadvantage of using `*` is when there are column names which exists on both tables. It causes ambiguity or if not, only the columns on the first table will show, ignoring the other columns on other tables having the same name..

Comment: select a.*, b.hobby.... you can use the tablename.* to select every column from that single table

Answer (score 0):

Hope u need the data in that format mentioned above not a table.
here i have mentioned the query to get the data like u asked

SELECT a.id,a.first_name,a.sport,b.hobby FROM `table1` a LEFT JOIN `table2` b ON a.first_name=b.name

just execute the above query in ur phpmyadmin then implement it in ur php code 
Hope its helpful to u